# Confused about reverse ManyToMany Django with extended User

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

So i have a `userprofile` that extends from User.  Each `UserProfile` has a `manyToMany` with `Effect_module`. I want to add an author field on the effects model that has the name of the User

```
class Effect_module(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    html = models.TextField(default='')
    css = models.TextField(default='')
    js = models.TextField(default='')
    up_votes = models.IntegerField()
    down_votes = models.IntegerField()
    ##############################################
    author = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    effects = models.ManyToManyField(Effect_module)
```

In my template `effect.author` prints `"effect_modules.UserProfile.None"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the docs, i saw that i was'nt calling .all on the userprofile object.  I also saw that when your doing a reverse m2m a _set property is set that contains all the data.  Good stuff, thanks guys

I then had to loop through each main array and do my thing.

```
{% for author in effect.userprofile_set.all %}
    {{ author.user.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, can the Effect_module have more than one author? If so, you don't need to have the ManytoMany in the UserProfile model at all.

And also you can't call ManytoMany fields that way,  you do that by `.all`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

So you would use `effect.author.all`.

Comment: yes the Effect_module will be able to have more than one user.  So im looping through the effects showing all of them in the template....i want to show the author(s) in the loop with the existing data.  When i tried what you said, it returns an empty array...am i not assigning something correctly?